# ¿Cuál es el equivalente de "mind blowing" en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Más concretamente estoy buscando una expresión en español que exprese el mismo sentimiento que este emoji, pero no se me viene a la mente:

[image]

Una búsqueda en internet relaciona ese emoji con "mind blowing". Para dicho término se encuentra:

> [mind blowing](https://www.yourdictionary.com/mind-blowing):
>
> The definition of mind blowing is something that is so shocking, surprising, unexpected or wonderful that your brain cannot comprehend it.

El traductor de Google y algunos [ejemplos](https://context.reverso.net/traduccion/ingles-espanol/mind-blowing) de otros sitios de traducción sugieren el término *alucinante*.

> [alucinante](https://dle.rae.es/?id=28eKbTs)
>
> 1. adj. Que alucina.
> 2. adj. Fantástico, asombroso.

Me parece que *alucinar* ([*Sorprender, asombrar, deslumbrar*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=28fwlxV), según el DLE) no transmite idea de "mind blowing". Entiendo dicho término como no solo que algo te asombra sino que también te hace cambiar de opinión, o que te hacer ver algo de una forma totalmente distinta a antes, pero puedo estar equivocado.

Un ejemplo del uso que busco es esta frase:

> Leer tu blog fue [término similar a mind-blowing]. ¡Cambió de repente todo lo que creía saber acerca de motivación y expectativas al trabajar en un proyecto!

Comment: Interesante la pregunta.  Pero por favor, danos una frase que muestre cómo quieres usar la palabra.

Comment: Si buscas un adjetivo es difícil darle la misma connotación, pero en Argentina se dice *vuelapelos* (de *volarle los pelos [a alguien]*).

Answer (score 6):

En muchos países se usa "volarle (a alguien) la cabeza", aunque también puede tener el sentido de dispararle a alguien a la cabeza.

> ***volarle la cabeza (a alguien)***. par.
>
> Col. Alucinarle.
>
> Bol. Pero amaba Bolivia y lo del flautista le volaba la cabeza. Rivero, La piedra 732/1242.
>
> Méx. Siéntate bien que esto te va a volar la cabeza. Fernández B., Azul 58/3147.

([Fuente](http://xn--diccionariovariantesespaol-4rc.org/glosario/c/cabeza))

En Internet se encuentran muchísimos ejemplos. Para evitar aquellos en que el sentido es "matar con un disparo en la cabeza", se pueden buscar ejemplos con dativo en primera y segunda persona: *me voló la cabeza, te vuela la cabeza*, etc.

Answer (score 3):

En España podrías usar *flipar*:

> **[flipar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=I5m76DG)**
>
> Del ingl. *to flip [out]* 'perder el control bajo los efectos de las
>   drogas', 'volverse loco'.
>
> 2. intr. coloq. Esp. Estar o quedar maravillado o admirado. *La gente flipaba CON la música.* U. t. c. prnl.
> 3. intr. coloq. Esp. Estar o quedar asombrado o extrañado. *Flipamos al saber que fue monja.*

Algo *flipante* es algo que te puede provocar ese estado de asombro que te da el *mind-blowing*, de hecho la voz viene de *[mind] flip*. Yo diría que en el ejemplo de la acepción 3, "flipamos al saber que fue monja", se podría aplicar el emoji que propones.

También puedes decir que algo es *un [flipe](https://dle.rae.es/?id=I5uWirx)*.

Comment: ¿Also puede ser flipante?

Answer (score 2):

Propusiste **alucinante** pero estabas dudando.  Creo que es un término muy común para este concepto.

> 2 [sustancia] Que causa un cambio del tono afectivo, generalmente hacia la euforia, y que produce alteraciones perceptivas, en especial visiones.

Esta segunda definición encaja perfectamente con *mindblowing* ([American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mind-blowing)): 1. Producing hallucinatory effects: *mind-blowing drugs*; 2. Intensely affecting the mind or emotions: *a mind-blowing horror story*.

Pero en tu ejemplo también podrías decir *revolucionario*.

Answer (score 1):

El sentido de ***mind-blowing*** (tal como ***alucinar*** o ***volar la cabeza*** también representan) es

> **asombrar** ([ver](https://dle.rae.es/?id=42oF3Bx))

que, así como la fuente de la RAE muestra, significa causar [admiración](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0mcCwDF)

> **admirar**
>
> Del lat. admirāri.
>
> 1. tr. Causar **sorpresa** la vista o **consideración de algo extraordinario o inesperado**.
> 2. tr. Ver, contemplar o considerar con estima o agrado especiales a **alguien o algo que llaman la atención por cualidades juzgadas como extraordinarias**. U. t. c. prnl.
> 3. tr. Tener en singular estimación a alguien o algo, juzgándolos **sobresalientes y extraordinarios**.